# How to redirect to another page within an iframe?

Tags: redirect, iframe, cross-domain

I have an ecommerce that lives inside an iframe.
At a certain point I need to redirect the user to the checkout page, and my checkout provider is on another domain.

for example: my website is `www.a.example` and the provider is on `payments.b.example`.

I get blocked in doing this inside an iframe. How can I achieve my objective?

Comment: What code are you using when you get blocked?   Are you trying to redirect client side using JavaScript or server side using HTTP status redirects?

Comment: Server side HTTP redirect

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting, and what browser is giving it to you?